# "mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged" appears in syslog. What should I do?

Tags: hardware, error-handling

I have installed the latest version of [OSSEC](http://www.ossec.net/?page_id=19) (2.8.1) and I have also enabled email notifications. And I am getting loads of these sorts of notifications saying that there is a Hardware Error and something about mce:

```
OSSEC HIDS Notification.
2015 Apr 04 20:09:22

Received From: Bath-Towel->/var/log/syslog
Rule: 1002 fired (level 2) -> "Unknown problem somewhere in the system."
Portion of the log(s):

Apr  4 20:09:21 Bath-Towel kernel: [ 1873.680872] mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged



 --END OF NOTIFICATION
```

So what exactly does this mean? What does mce stand for? And is this apparent hardware error anything that I should worry about?

---

**OS Information:**

```
Description:    Ubuntu 14.10
Release:    14.10
```

Comment: You will need to do a bit of reading on ossec, see the rules - http://ossec-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/rules-decoders/ . The web interface helps as it has a number of explanations - http://www.ossec.net/wiki/index.php/OSSECWUI:Install

Comment: http://ossec-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq/alerts.html#how-do-i-ignore-rule-1002

Comment: ossec is probably poorly supported or off topic here as it is not in the ubuntu repositories

Comment: This is not about OSSEC at all. You got that notification because OSSEC found the word "error" in syslog. Although I don't think it is off-topic, you'll probably get more help form [unix.se] or [sf].

Comment: @bodhi.zazen All it has to do to be on-topic is run on Ubuntu. Now that doesn't mean you'll get an answer of course.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[Machine Check Exception](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine-check_exception):

> A **Machine Check Exception (MCE)** is a type of computer hardware
>   error that occurs when a computer's central processing unit detects a
>   hardware problem.

Your computer experienced a hardware error and the kernel logged an event in a buffer. You can use `mcelog` to log and view the machine check events. From [`mcelog` manpage](http://mcelog.org/manpage.html):

> X86 CPUs report errors detected by the CPU as machine check events
>   (MCEs). These can be data corruption detected in the CPU caches, in
>   main memory by an integrated memory controller, data transfer errors
>   on the front side bus or CPU interconnect or other internal errors.
>   Possible causes can be cosmic radiation, instable power supplies,
>   cooling problems, broken hardware, running systems out of
>   specification, or bad luck.
>
> Most errors can be corrected by the CPU by internal error correction
>   mechanisms. Uncorrected errors cause machine check exceptions which
>   may kill processes or panic the machine. A small number of corrected
>   errors is usually not a cause for worry, but a large number can
>   indicate future failure.
>
> When a corrected or recovered error happens the x86 kernel writes a
>   record describing the MCE into a internal ring buffer available
>   through the /dev/mcelog device. mcelog retrieves errors from
>   /dev/mcelog, decodes them into a human readable format and prints them
>   on the standard output or optionally into the system log.

If you didn't notice any crash, probably the error was successfully corrected. Still, I advise you to install `mcelog` to keep track of such events:

```
sudo apt-get install mcelog
```

The events will be logged to `/var/log/mcelog`. You can also run:

```
sudo mcelog --client
```

to query the `mcelog` daemon for errors.

Comment: I wonder why MCE errors aren't just written directly to a system log... probably *some* good reason, maybe

Comment: @Xen2050 Because the decoding of the message is architecture dependent and it is not always documented by hardware manufacturers. The error could be generated even by PCIe bus.

Comment: @Xen2050: On my Fedora 25 machine, the MCE messages get written to the journal, I can see them with `journalctl -b`.

Comment: @MartinUeding : `journalctl -b` works also on Debian 10 "Buster". The `mcelog` package does not seem to be available, however.

Comment: @LaryxDecidua On Debian 10 the functionality has been replaced by `rasdaemon`

Answer (score 0):

This tool has been replaced by: `rasdaemon`

https://packages.debian.org/de/sid/rasdaemon