# Ubuntu does not resume after suspend - Lenovo IdeaPad z510

Tags: suspend, lenovo, resume

My OS hangs during starting resume. (Suspend works fine.)
System can be rebooted only with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> + <kbd>REISUB</kbd>.

I have tried downgrade kernel. It does not work(
["mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged" appears in syslog. What should I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/605369/mce-hardware-error-machine-check-events-logged-appears-in-syslog-what-sho)).
*Updated:*
Resume for virtual console does not work too(
[Unable to resume after suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/436133/unable-to-resume-after-suspend?rq=1)).

**OS Information:**

```
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10 wily
Kernel: x86_64 Linux 4.2.0-27-generic
```

*Question*: How to resolve the issue? Any suggestions.
            How to prepare a well bug for developers?

**kernel.log:**

```
Feb  8 08:08:20 Z510 kernel: [   54.041077] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG1.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150619/nsarguments-95)
Feb  8 08:08:20 Z510 kernel: [   54.041196] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG1.PEGP: failed to evaluate _DSM
Feb  8 08:08:20 Z510 kernel: [   54.041200] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG1.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150619/nsarguments-95)
Feb  8 08:08:21 Z510 kernel: [   54.940742] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
Feb  8 08:08:21 Z510 kernel: [   54.940749] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
Feb  8 08:08:21 Z510 kernel: [   54.940754] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
Feb  8 08:11:54 Z510 gnome-session[2518]: Entering running state
Feb  8 08:12:26 Z510 kernel: [  300.144014] mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
Feb  8 08:44:10 Z510 kernel: [ 2205.698722] usb 1-10.2: USB disconnect, device number 5
Feb  8 08:58:00 Z510 kernel: [ 3037.033616] usb 1-10.3: new low-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
Feb  8 08:58:00 Z510 kernel: [ 3037.143482] usb 1-10.3: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c31d
Feb  8 08:58:00 Z510 kernel: [ 3037.143485] usb 1-10.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Feb  8 08:58:00 Z510 kernel: [ 3037.143487] usb 1-10.3: Product: USB Keyboard
Feb  8 08:58:00 Z510 kernel: [ 3037.143489] usb 1-10.3: Manufacturer: Logitech
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated my OS.
Suspend-resume works fine with Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS