# Crash RIP !INEXACT!

Tags: server, 18.04, crash

[image]

My ubuntu system (Ubuntu 18.04 Server) keeps crashing. The error is above. It shows up different every time. I have a Core-i7 2600K. Does anybody know why? Can I add more detail here? I feel like I can, I don't know how.

Comment: Judging by the CPU 3: Machine Check Exception: 5 Bank 3 listed there, you might have a bad RAM stick.  See:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/605369/mce-hardware-error-machine-check-events-logged-appears-in-syslog-what-sho

Comment: @Terrance Remount RAM? Its running fine as of now, I had the CPU turbo set to 4.3 GHZ and the i7 2600K's Max turbo is supposed to be 3.8 so i underclocked the Turbo clock. If the crash happens again ill try remounting RAM. Right now im playing terraria on the computer. Its being utilized as a server.

Comment: You can try reseating / remounting the RAM.  I can also see overclocking causing RAM failures.  With overclocking good cooling is a must!

Comment: Good cooling indeed! 35C Idle 50C Load. I just got the cooler today. Thats why I have the terraria server now. Before i was hitting 80-90 with the stock cooler at which point i would shutdown. so i got this new cooler the Noctua NH D9L.

Comment: If cooling solved the problem then please delete the question. This question is then hardware related and off topic here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic  because it is hardware related.

Comment: Did your server use to work fine and just start crashing after an update?

Comment: @PythonDude29 I'm confused. Are you saying all the problems are solved now by installing thermal management system? If so then your question will be closed as a hardware problem.

Comment: Guys, hardware issues are not off-topic. Per [Seth](https://askubuntu.com/questions/605369/mce-hardware-error-machine-check-events-logged-appears-in-syslog-what-sho#comment846817_605369), "All it has to do to be on-topic is run on Ubuntu."

Comment: GUYS, CALM DOWN. It was not the cooling that solved the problem, it was merely the cooler that motivated me to do stuff on my server. See my answer below.

Comment: None of these comment answers are correct except the part about overclocking causing RAM issues and CPU issues. It was not the Cooler, not an update, the boot itself says Hardware Error. But the hardware error's roots are from the bios over-turboing my cpu as in my answer below.

Comment: @Terrance The MCE hardware error page you linked me, the top answer says that one of the problems could be "running your system out of specification" aka  ASUS running the cpu with max turbo of 3.8 GHZ at 4.3GHZ

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is BIOS-related, not Ubuntu-related as per OP's answer.

Comment: @PythonDude29 Yep, running it out of specification can definitely do that.  Unfortunately, just looking at the pic you have here posted, I could only come up with the guess based off the pic and nothing more.

Answer (score 2):

My problem turned out to be that ASUS's "Optimized Defaults" were just garbage, causing my Core i7-2600K, with a max Turbo Speed of 3.8 GHZ to try to turbo all the way to 4.3 GHZ, therefore causing the cpu to stop working, then the computer shutdown and rebooted repeatedly. When I discovered this, switching through the BIOS, I turned it off and as far as I can tell, it works now. I ran a stress test overnight and its still on this morning with a max temp of 60C.