# Black screen installing Ubuntu Server 20.04.2 from USB

Tags: server, grub2, system-installation, usb-installation

I've created an Ubuntu Server 20.04.02 USB drive with Rufus, but when trying to install it on a brand new machine it dies after the GRUB screen when I select "Install Ubuntu Server". It's not just a black screen, the monitor goes to sleep and loses the input entirely.

There's a brief (milliseconds) flash of text before it goes off, which says:

```
[ 0.129215 ] mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 0: Machine Check: 0 Bank 6: ee20000000
[ 0.129217 ] mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 0 ADDR fef1e680 MISC 43880000086
[ 0.129220 ] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:a0653 TIME 1617381661 SOCKET 0
APIC 0 microcode e0
```

It's a brand new build with an H510M-ITX/ac mobo and G5905 cpu, so I'm not sure if it's a hardware error or even how I'd find out which part is causing it if so. The BIOS is on the latest version (there's only one). No graphics card so don't think it's a driver thing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["mce: \[Hardware Error\]: Machine check events logged" appears in syslog. What should I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/605369/mce-hardware-error-machine-check-events-logged-appears-in-syslog-what-sho)

Comment: I'm not sure if those answers will help me - I can't get into any shell, so I can't run those commands. It crashes but I can't see how to figure out why from those errors

Comment: Read it again - the link is intended to help you understand the problem: The kernel is reporting faulty hardware. Fix your hardware issue before trying to install Ubuntu.

Comment: @user535733 I have the same error, but Windows installs and works ok on the same machine. Is it a sign that the hardware is ok?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it - needed to add `nomodeset` to the kernel params in the GRUB screen, and then permanently add it to GRUB config once ubuntu was installed.

Comment: I had the same issue with an Intel Core i3-10100 and an ASRock H510-ITX. Was resolved with your answer.