# Memory failure: unhandlable page. / RAS

Tags: kernel, hardware, ram

Im new to desktop Ubuntu and I have errors in my `/var/log/syslog`

When I started debugging this I initially thought that my stock memory was busted, so I went out and bought new memory. The problem persisted so I thought my motherboard was the problem, went out and bought a new motherboard. But now after installing everything I'm still getting the error in the logs.

I have run memcheck86 and gotten 0 errors. I have also ran a memory test in windows with 0 errors. I'm dualbooting windows 11 and ubuntu 23.04, I also have Pop OS installed on a separate drive.

Windows seems to be working fine or is hiding the error (can't find anything in logs). But both installs of ubuntu output the information below in the syslog. Does anyone have a clue on how to fix this?

```
2023-10-28T16:14:16.294569+02:00 Legion-T7-34IMZ5 kernel: [  121.976069] mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
2023-10-28T16:14:17.286495+02:00 Legion-T7-34IMZ5 kernel: [  122.968104] mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
2023-10-28T16:14:19.274495+02:00 Legion-T7-34IMZ5 kernel: [  124.956066] RAS: Soft-offlining pfn: 0x103fa86
2023-10-28T16:14:19.274501+02:00 Legion-T7-34IMZ5 kernel: [  124.956770] Memory failure: 0x103fa86: unhandlable page.
2023-10-28T16:14:24.294579+02:00 Legion-T7-34IMZ5 kernel: [  129.976160] RAS: Soft-offlining pfn: 0x26
2023-10-28T16:14:24.294585+02:00 Legion-T7-34IMZ5 kernel: [  129.976300] Memory failure: 0x26: unhandlable page.
```

## Setup:

- Lenovo Legion T7 34imz5
- OS: Ubuntu 23.04 / Pop os (22.04) / Windows 11
- CPU: Intel 11th gen i9-11900KF @ 3.50Ghz
- Memory: 64gb (4x16gb Kingston Fury Renegade DDR4 SDRAM 3600 MHz non-ecc, brand new)
- GPU: Nvidia 3080TI 16gb
- Motherboard: MSI Z490 GAMING PLUS(brand new)

Comment: which OS is causing the issue? PopOS or Ubuntu?

Comment: @graham same error in both

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/608156/15811  Focus on the 1st error, not the last. Your CPU has a problem so it is not memory. Check mcelog for the actual message.

Comment: @Rinzwind that was indeed the problem, bought a new CPU and now everything works, no more errors.

Comment: Nice! Hopefully not too expensive ;)